# applying css to dynamically generated radio buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hi I have a javascript code that generates radio buttons and remove as well if required.
        
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){        
        Node.childNodes[i].innerHTML = "";        
    }

```
var Node1 = document.getElementById(tempArrIndex);        <br>
arrValueOptions = childValues[tempArrIndex["Values"].split(",");
for (var tempC2 = 0; tempC2 < arrValueOptions.length; tempC2++){
    var nameToUpdate = holdIDsToUpdate[tempCounter];
    var temp = tempC2 + 1;
    var idToUpdate = holdIDsToUpdate[tempCounter] + temp;
    var labelToUpdate = "";
    var defUpdater = "";
    if (arrValueOptions[tempC2] != ""){
        labelToUpdate = arrValueOptions[tempC2];
        if (childValues[tempArrIndex]["Default"] == labelToUpdate){
            defUpdater = 1;
        }
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.class = "test";
        var data1 = document.createElement("td");
        var newRadio = document.createElement("input");
        newRadio.type = "radio";
        newRadio.id = idToUpdate;
        newRadio.name = nameToUpdate;
        newRadio.value = labelToUpdate;
        if (defUpdater == 1){
            newRadio.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }
        newRadio.setAttribute("onclick", "javascript:dependentFieldsValue('" + idToUpdate + "');");
        var data11 = document.createElement("td")
        var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
        newLabel.htmlFor = idToUpdate;
        newLabel.id = idToUpdate;
        newLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(labelToUpdate));
        tbody.appendChild(row);
        row.appendChild(data1);
        data1.appendChild(newRadio);
        row.appendChild(data11);
        data11.appendChild(newLabel);
        Node1.appendChild(row);
        defUpdater = 0;
    }
}
```

It works fine , what I need to do is to create gap in between radio buttons in a group. as they are very close to each other. any one please help. Gap appears fine in IE but not in Firefox.

Comment: mh, maybe you should format your code first, it's unreadable this way. And use css-padding or margin for gaps, it's pretty easy.

Comment: You are counting on browser's CSS styling to style gap/positioning of your elements. If you wish to keep a gap, you need to apply a style on your radio elements - and set margin in the same.

Comment: And are you sure it works?  You've got way too many close braces than you do open braces...

Comment: Hmmmm... Thanks Jan , i will post it in readable format..... Thanks Aditya , actually i have tough hand on CSS.... i tried it but let me try again and will let u know.....Hi tkone actually i picked it u from my piece of code it works there..may i copied few extra brackets..yes it works fine... thanks

Answer (score 0):

A gap can be obtained through some CSS applying a padding on `td` cells in which you append your checkboxes, e.g.

```
td { padding: 0.5em 0 }
```

Comment: hi Calderan Thanks.... for your reply.. problems look bit diffrent ..let me explain you guys.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your generated radio buttons, like this:

```
newRadio.className = "myClass";
```

then you can just add whatever css to all your radio buttons as follows:

```
.myClass {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```